# mvc razor refresh image after uploading a new one

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i hava a problem with refreshing an image after uploading a new one. 
By clicking on the change button i want to upload a new image and the old one should be refreshed. Do you have an idea how to solve that?

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Logos/{0}.png", ViewData["companyName"]))" alt="Loading..." />
<input class="btn btn-default"  id="changeButton" type="button" value="Logo ändern"/><br/>
<input id="uploadLogo" type="file" name="logoName" style="display: none">
```

With jQuery i starting the file upload by clicking on the changeButton

```
    $('#changeButton').click(function () {
    $('#uploadLogo').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: will you plz explain what exactly do you want???

Comment: please try it 
http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/LvsYc/1669/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an input of type "file" then you can do this in two ways.

One is that you upload the picture to the database/project via AJAX and send back
the url of the image. and append the url to your image src attribute

Another approach that is supported from ie9 and above is that you can catch the event of the 
upload in jquery and get the url from the clients computer. and append it to the src tag of you img attribute

Note that the second soloution does not upload/save the picture to your project/datbase but it gives you a preview of the picture.

The possibility of you saving the images using the second approach is possible with yet another AJAX call to the server but i would recommend using it as a preview and add a new button "save" to save it.